# Is applying chain rule in Trigonometric function wrong?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, chain-rule

> Find $dy/dx$ if $y = x \sin x$.

I was trying to solve the problem following way.

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x]=x\cos x$$

So,

$$\frac{d}{dx}[x \sin x]$$
$$=>x\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x]+\sin x \frac{d}{dx}[x]$$
$$=>x^2 \cos x+\sin x$$

But, when I saw answer in *Calculus by Howard Anton* book I saw my answer was wrong.

> [image]

> $$\frac{d}{dx}[x \sin x]$$
> $$=>x\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x]+\sin x \frac{d}{dx}[x]$$
> $$=>x \cos x+\sin x$$

Why the book answer didn't apply chain rule? So, is applying chain rule in Trigonometric function  wrong?

---

In my Physics, I found an equation

$$x=A \sin (\omega t)$$

When they differentiate `x` than, they wrote something just like this.

$$x=A\omega \cos (\omega t)$$

I just used chain in my main question from this method.
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x]=x \cos x$$

Actually, What am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}[sinx]=x\cos x$ is not right.

Comment: @Amelia So, you are saying that I am right, aren't you? Yes! They haven't introduced the chain rule. That's in next chapter..

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your question. The Chain Rule is badly applied on your solution.

Comment: @Amelia Please! Check that isn't it chain rule? $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x)))=[f′(g(x))g′(x)]$$ Here's [a picture](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcalcworkshop.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fchain-rule-formula.png&f=1&nofb=1)... I know that Chain rule is applied as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$$. But, what's that I first wrote?

Comment: The chain rule states that under the right hypothesis, the derivative of the composition $f \circ g$ at the point $x$ is $f'(g(x))g'(x)$. If you want to derive the function $f'(g(x))g'(x)$, then  you need to apply the product and chain rules, but I don't know what this has to do with your original question.

Comment: Your example talks about the *product* of the functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=sin(x)$, there isn't a composition involved. That's why to compute the derivative you use the product rule. I think what is confusing you is that, in the chain rule, the derivative at a point results to be a product of numbers (the product of $f'(g(x))$ and $g'(x)$). Try to reread it and remember that the chain rule is applied only when a composition is involved.

Comment: @Amelia *Unfortunately, there's no equation $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x)))=[f'(g(x))g'(x)]$$ like this in Calculus by Howard Anton's book.* Did you mean I can't use chain rule inside product rule? But, isn't $$\frac{d}{dx}[sinx]=x\cos x$$ it correct? Cause, when I apply chain rule than I get it..

Comment: I don't have this Calculus book but I'm almost sure it introduces sooner or later the chain rule, probably it states it in an alternative way. The expression I wrote and the expression you wrote just differ in notation, but talk about the same. When starting learning calculus, I find the expression $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$ rather misleading; I suggest you to first understand the Chain rule stated as "$(f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$".

Comment: @Amelia OK! Let me learn Chain Rule more properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \frac{d}{dx}[\sin x] = \cos x$,
not $ x\cos x$.

Your understanding of the Physics text is probably mistaken. In it, $\omega$ is a constant. The application of chain rule would go:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(A\sin(\omega t)) = A \cos (\omega t) \frac{d}{dt}(\omega t) = A\omega \cos (\omega t).$$

In contrast, the expression inside your sin term has no constant attached (or more precisely, that constant is 1, so it's basically invisible). Your expression is a special case of the above expression with $A=\omega=1$.

Comment: Ohh! Finally I have understood what I was missing☺

Comment: No problem, everyone makes conceptual errors like that all the time :D

Answer (score 0):

At the given case, the appropriate property to be applied is the product rule.

It says that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions defined and differentiable at $x\in \mathbb{R}$, where $x$ is a limit point, then the following relation holds:
\begin{align*}
[f(x)g(x)]' = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)
\end{align*}

At your case, $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The notation $X\to Y$ is really not helping, imo.

Comment: @KentaS Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. I am going to edit it.

Comment: Sorry! I just tried as you said. But, I wrote $$f(x)g′(x)+f′(x)g(x)$$ instead of $$f′(x)g(x)+f(x)g′(x)$$.. Both are same.. So, it totally isn't my answer..